# How to calculate lm coefficients such that test statistics remain valid

Tags: r

I need help with a supposedly simple task but I'm not able to find a solution. Suppose to fit a simple linear model such like

`model <- lm(Y~ a_1 + a_2, data=mydata)`

Now ideally in my output I would like to report the coefficient on `a_1` as the ratio of `a_2/a_1` (= ratio of estimates!) in a way such that my test statistics i.e. standard errors are correct. Here a reproducable example of how to calculate the estimate I want to report in my output:

```
a_2 <- 1:20
a_1 <- 20:40
Y <- 1
mydata <- as.data.frame(cbind(Y, a_1, a_2))
model <- lm(Y~a_1+a_2, data=mydata)
coef <- coefficients(model)
coef[2] <- coef[3]/coef[2]     # the estimate I want to report in my output
```

I'm using stargazer for my output `stargazer(model)` and the package provides the `apply.coef` function, but I do not know if this can do what I'm looking for. Or is there a way of specifying that in my `lm` function directly?

Answer (score 1):

This may go a bit beyond what you're asking, but I'd like to demonstrate how you can use a Bayesian model with `rstan` to get realistic estimates of model parameter-derived quantities, such as the ratio of two parameters in a simple linear model.

(One of) the benefit(s) of a Bayesian approach is having access to and robustly dealing with the propagation of the full posterior densities of all parameters. Uncertainties therefore automatically get properly propagated to any custom derived quantity that is a function of the parameters.

Here is a worked-through example using the `Ginzberg` data from R library `car`.

1. Load the `rstan` and `car` libraries.

   ```
   library(rstan);
   library(car);
   ```
2. Define a simple linear model with implicit uniform priors; uniform priors are generally not a good idea. We keep them here to make results more comparable to results from the `lm` model further down.

   ```
   model <- "
   data {
       int N;            // Number of observations
       int K;            // Number of model parameters
       real y[N];        // Response vector
       matrix[N,K] X;    // Data/model matrix
   }
   parameters {
       vector[K] beta;   // Model coefficients
       real sigma;       // Standard deviation
   }

   model {
       y ~ normal(X * beta, sigma);   // Likelihood
   }

   generated quantities {
       real ratio;
       ratio = beta[2] / beta[3];
   }"
   ```

   Note the `generated quantities` block where we calculate a derived `ratio` parameter as the ratio of `beta[2]` and `beta[3]`.
3. From the Ginzberg depression data we model `depression ~ simplicity + fatalism` with a non-zero intercept.

   ```
   ## Sample data
   # Ginzberg data on depression included in R library "car"
   X <- model.matrix(~ simplicity + fatalism, data = Ginzberg);
   ```
4. Fit the Stan model and show fit results.

   ```
   # Fit the model in Stan
   fit.stan <- stan(
       model_code = model,
       data = list(N = nrow(X), K = 3, y = Ginzberg$depression, X = X))
   fit.stan;
   #Inference for Stan model: d0cfe0c2eab6991c34e2d242b74ea832.
   #4 chains, each with iter=2000; warmup=1000; thin=1;
   #post-warmup draws per chain=1000, total post-warmup draws=4000.
   #
   #         mean se_mean   sd  2.5%   25%   50%   75% 97.5% n_eff Rhat
   #beta[1]  0.20    0.00 0.10  0.01  0.13  0.20  0.26  0.39  2718    1
   #beta[2]  0.38    0.00 0.11  0.17  0.31  0.38  0.45  0.60  1887    1
   #beta[3]  0.42    0.00 0.10  0.21  0.35  0.42  0.49  0.61  1896    1
   #sigma    0.36    0.00 0.03  0.30  0.34  0.35  0.38  0.42  3042    1
   #ratio    0.65    0.02 1.40  0.02  0.32  0.52  0.80  1.88  3401    1
   #lp__    44.19    0.04 1.48 40.40 43.46 44.51 45.29 46.06  1332    1
   #
   #Samples were drawn using NUTS(diag_e) at Thu Apr 19 21:58:12 2018.
   #For each parameter, n_eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
   #and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor on split chains (at
   #convergence, Rhat=1).
   ```

   Note that `beta[1]` is the offset, `beta[2]` the `simplicity` coefficient, and `beta[3]` the `fatalism` coefficient. `ratio` is the derived `simplicity/fatalism` coefficient ratio. `sigma` is the standard deviation of the normal error term.

   Since we defined a "generated quantity", we have the full posterior distribution (and along with that the standard deviation, confidence interval etc.) for our derived `ratio` parameter.
5. Because it's easy we also plot parameter estimates including confidence intervals. We can see the large uncertainty associated with the derived `ratio` parameter estimate.

   ```
   plot(fit.stan);
   #ci_level: 0.8 (80% intervals)
   #outer_level: 0.95 (95% intervals)
   ```

[image]

4. We can compare our parameter estimates with point estimates from `lm`.

   ```
   fit.lm <- lm(depression ~ simplicity + fatalism, data = Ginzberg);
   coef.est <- summary(fit.lm)$coef[, 1];
   coef.sd <- summary(fit.lm)$coef[, 2];
   cbind.data.frame(coef.est, coef.sd);
   #             coef.est    coef.sd
   #(Intercept) 0.2026931 0.09472399
   #simplicity  0.3795328 0.10063518
   #fatalism    0.4177744 0.10063504
   ```

   We can now also calculate a ratio and propagate the standard deviation from both parameters using [Gauss' law for the propagation of uncertainties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty).

   ```
   ratio <- unname(coef.est[2] / coef.est[3]);
   ratio.sd <- unname(ratio * sqrt((coef.sd[2]/coef.est[2])^2 + (coef.sd[3]/coef.est[3])^2));
   cbind.data.frame(ratio, ratio.sd);
   #      ratio  ratio.sd
   #1 0.9084635 0.3254435
   ```

   It is clear that this naive approach **underestimates** the uncertainty in `ratio`.

Comment: Maurits, thank you for this very detailed answer and the demonstration of the differences among the two approaches. For the "naive" approach is there a possibility to tell `lm` upfront that I want estimates for ratios? For larger models, calculating it manually is maybe inefficient.

Comment: @user9660581 Telling `lm` "upfront" what other derived quantities you'd like to calculate is not possible. That's because this process is completely unrelated to the actual model fitting. Perhaps think of it as a *post-hoc* derived parameter estimation. I'd advise against using this approach; you can see that even when using the law for the propagation of uncertainties you are severely underestimating the uncertainty in the derived parameter. I would imagine this effect to be critically depend on the collinearity between parameters and on posterior parameter densities being non-normal. [...]

Comment: [continued] A Bayesian approach has many advantages and allows you to include as many derived quantities as you need upfront; collinearity is also less of an issue if you use weakly informative (regularising) priors. All these will lead to (1) more robust parameter estimates for derived parameters, and (2) more reliable estimates of associated uncertainties. Does this clear things up?

Comment: Yes that clears things up for me, thank you! However, I guess I have to be clearer on what model I'm fitting. It looks as follows (with the short term omitted) Y=∅(β0+β1X_t+β2γ_t )+ε_t. Estimating this equation with `lm` function gives coefficients for ∅ which is the adjustment parameter, β_1 the coefficient on X_t and β_2, the coefficient on γ_t. I have to divide both estimates β_1 and β_2 by the estimate ∅ to obtain the desired coefficients. Thus, I need ratios because the estimates of interest (=β_1 and β_2 ) enter multiplicatively with another estimate (=∅). Does this change things?

Comment: @user9660581 The formatting of your LM aside, your model looks strange. Your model (let's call it model 1) `alpha * (beta0 + beta1 x_t + beta2 gamma_t) + epsilon` can be rewritten as `beta0_prime + beta1_prime x_t + beta2_prime gamma_t + epsilon` (model 2), and `lm` will produce OLS estimates for `beta0_prime`, `beta1_prime` and `beta2_prime`. Fitting model 1 will lead to unstable solutions, and does not make sense; `alpha` is not a multiplicative coefficient, because it can simply be absorbed in the other additive model parameters.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake but this should be an Error Correction Model of the following form (using your expressions): `delta Y = alpha * (beta0 + beta1 x_t-1 + beta2 gamma_t-1 + (A_t-1 - Y_t-1)) + epsilon`. Desired coefficients are sill beta1 and beta2.

Comment: Which in R looks as follows: `model1 <- lm(dY~I(A_1-Y_1) + x_1 + gamma_1, data=mydata)`

Comment: @user9660581 Not sure I understand. Your last model will simply give you coefficients `beta0_prime`, `beta1_prime`, `beta2_prime` and `beta3_prime` (corresponding to `intercept`, `x_1`, `gamma_1` and difference term. There is no `alpha` in the `lm` model, and more generally estimating `alpha` makes no sense, because it can be absorbed in the other coefficients.

Comment: yes correct, I get the coefficients you mentioned and `alpha` is in fact not estimated, but it should be given by the term `I(A_1-Y_1)`. The estimates of this equation are lagged by one period and reflect the deviation from equilibrium in the previous period. Thus one could simply estimate `alpha` by taking the lagged residuals from the LR equation `Y = beta0 + beta1 x_t + beta2 gamma_t + A_t + epsilon`. by `resid <- lag(residuals(model))` and include them in the SR equation `dY~resid_1 + dx,` where `resid_1` would be `alpha` (=speed of adjustment) and `dx` the SR variable.

Comment: To be concrete, the above would imply a two step approach (first estimate the LR than the SR equation), but I would like to estimate both in one-step.

Comment: @user9660581 Not sure if this is possible or makes sense. Your problem statement has changed significantly from your original post. I recommend closing this question by setting the check mark and then asking a new question in a separate post; perhaps Cross Validated might be a better fit for such a question, as it seems less about coding and more about statistical modelling.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help!